# CSS UL Menu IE wont view correcty

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to use a menu on my site. So I have prepared it, it works fine on Firefox, Chrome, Safari but not on IE. Here is the [link](http://minas.miroglu.com/testing/) to that little html, its a menu with li items. Any idea how to make it work on IE as well? Also afaik css gradient backgrounds should work on IE, but it does not :

Comment: Use a styled unordered list, not DIVs to build menus. Other than positioning, put all styling on the A-tag. See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/

Comment: @Diodeus: I never really understood the full reason to prefer <ul> over <div> for navigation. Semantic, less markup, easier to style with CSS, accepted axion by the community, nav element in HTML5? Still I see that 99% of navigation are made up with <ul> but any of the reason above is open for debate with pros and cons going in each favour. Offcourse I maybe just silly and missing some point not in the above.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, its a better practice but why IE cannot handle this one?

Comment: Use @Diodeus so that he gets your comments in his inbox rather than re-visting the question to see any updates. They might just miss your comments and not get back to you.

Comment: The NAV tag is a container that tells the browser "the stuff in here is navigation". It's a semantic tag. What you put inside is really up to you.

Comment: cevizmx: ul, li is used to allow screen readers to see the items as a list to allow the user to easily follow the chain. A list contains semantic information "I'm a list" whereas a bunch of DIVs could be anything.